# How can I fix the Wii Forecast channel on RiiConnect24 (Error Code: FORE000006)?

Tags: technical-issues, nintendo-wii, homebrew

I'm getting the following error on the Forecast Channel after configuring RiiConnect24:

> Unable to download the latest information.
>
> Error Code: FORE000006

I have ensured that my date and time are configured correctly, and waited one hour as per the instructions on [Wii.guide](https://wii.guide/riiconnect24-batteryfix.html), but I am still getting this error.

I have also tried powering the system off and on again, and even left the system unplugged for a day and plugged it back in, to no avail.

Is there any other way to fix this?

Comment: Why is this tagged 'homebrew'?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas RiiConnect24 is a homebrew application.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to fully reset the date/time on the Wii. To do this, you can pull the CR2032 battery which keeps the date/time set. This battery is easily accessible on most Wii models via a little battery cover hatch.

1. Unscrew the battery cover. Note that the screw will stay attached to the cover.
   [image: Wii battery cover]
2. Pull the cover and CR2032 battery out
   [image: CR2032 and battery cover detached from the Wii]
3. Leave the Wii unplugged and without battery for about an hour
4. Re-insert the battery/cover and screw back into position.
5. Power on the Wii, and go into the System Settings.
6. Set the date and time

After this, you should be able to launch the Forecast channel. If done correctly it will prompt you about the date/time and allow you to configure your local area for weather reports.

<sub>Images from [iFixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Nintendo+Wii+U+Console+Battery+Replacement/12589) - [CC-BY-NC-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)</sub>